# Detaching parts of engine bell

Tags: engine-design, engines

I was looking at engine bells, and I was wondering: would it be possible or useful for a diamond shaped engine bell, that would stage sections off, creating a wider bell as the rocket leaves the atmosphere? Would this be any benefit for SSTO vehicles?

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing what you mean.

Comment: The Vinci engine was at one time intended to have a telescoping nozzle to get the effect you mean (larger nozzle), but that would be extended before firing the engine.  https://spaceflightnow.com/news/n1406/17airbussafran/vinci_400266.jpg

Comment: @Hobbes - a nozzle expanding from throat to a vacuum-appropriate-diameter, at which point there would be a separation line, beyond which it would narrow back down to a sea-level-appropriate diameter. The question is, would the reconstriction ruin the performance of the engine.

Comment: Would there be any advantage over a "conventional" expandable nozzle? https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7pme.jpg

Comment: @OrganicMarble Much less weight in machinery carried in the final high-expansion configuration.

Comment: Ah, so basically adding a 2nd converging section.  That would decelerate the exhaust so there would be Isp losses.  Cooling the 2nd converging section would be interesting too. I guess the question is, would the performance loss due to exhaust velocity loss be greater than the gain from matching the exit plane pressure.  My gut says this isn't a good idea.

Comment: Same; even if there's no additional loss I can't see how this would be any better than a (stepped) dual bell.

Comment: A photo/drawing would result in a better answer. For SSTO there's the [Aerospike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerospike_engine) (inverted bell) and the [expanding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanding_nozzle) nozzle (retracting outer bell) - and some alternatives on those webpages. Single stage is only *really* useful for absolute simplicity, like a shoulder launched rocket; and even some of those are staged. Even model rockets can be multi-stage. Like a [railcar tugger](https://alliedpower.com/railcar-positioning-systems/), once you get it moving you don't need the extra dunnage.